# Code push - Release update to multiple version

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-code-push

My app already on market with these versions. 1.0 ,1.1 ,1.2, 1.2.1 and 1.2.2.
 And now I need to release an update to version 1.0 , 1.1 , 1.2.

I have try with

```
code-push release-react myaap-Android Android --deploymentName Production --targetBinaryVersion=1.0-1.2
```

But I got this error

```
[Error] Please use a semver-compliant target binary version range, for example "1.0.0", "*" or "^1.2.3"
```

My first 3 version is not using semantic versioning, so how can I send update to them?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the following range for that: >=1.0.0 <1.2.1